# SQL - using the same table in the outer query and in the sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I'm trying to understand the logic of the simple following query:

```
select *
from table1 as t1 cross join table2 as t2
where t2.source_code = (
    select Max(t3.source_code)
    from table2 t3
    where t3.source_code in (t1.code_value)
    )
```

I've read about sub queries, also iv'e been searching for a related question as mine, i haven't found a clear answer.

My question is how can i know the complexity of this query (how many times the sub-query runs).

I'm not quite sure how the sub query works here as i use a table from the outer query inside the sub query.

Comment: There is never a conclusive answer when it comes to performance. That may vary based ob your indexes, table sizes ETC. Run an execution plan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This (Terrible, Horrible, No Good, Very Bad) query is equivalent to:

```
select * from table1 as t1 join table2 as t2 on t1.code_value = t2.source_code;
```

If the relation between tables is 1:1 or 1:N then the theoretical complexity is O(n).
The actual complexity is database/data structures/statistics dependent.

Comment: Right! As it is not immediately evident, maybe it is good to underline that the max() is totally useless in the original query, as `source_code` in the sub query has a single value that is determined by the `t3.source_code in (t1.code_value)` condition

Comment: @Insac, but then, the whole sub-query is useless... :-) I really, really hope this is not a real-life code.

Comment: I share your hope :-)